# Letters correspondence in RDF/XML

Tags: xml, uri, rdf, letter

I want to put a table into RDF/XML but I never did before. My table is concerning letters: Who wrote whom and when.

So my **question** is: 
Can I use the GND-numbers for the persons as URIs? Otherwise where did I get the URIs?
And is there an URI for "writes letter to" and "date"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, and part of the question is off-topic for Stack Overflow, I think.

> Can I use the GND-numbers for the persons as URIs? Otherwise where did I get the URIs?

I'm not familiar with GND numbers, though the typical English name seems like it might be [Integrated Authority File](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Authority_File), but if it's not a URI, then you can't use it as a URI.  You could certainly incorporate it into a URI.  Based on the [image on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Authority_File#mediaviewer/File:Gemeinsame_Normdatei_2012_Opera.png), you *could* use something like the **Link zu diesem Datensatz** field.  That said, you could use any URIs you want;  that's part of the beauty of the Semantic Web approach;  you can use whatever identifiers you want and figure out how to relate them later.  One popular approach is to use DPbedia identifiers, e.g., http://dbpedia.org/resource/Daniel_Webster for Daniel Webster.

> And is there an URI for "writes letter to" and "date"?

Again, you can use whatever URIs you want, but it may be useful to use URIs that other people are using.  There's no universal convention, and lots of vocabularies will have properties for this kind of concept, but you might find useful properties in DBpedia, e.g., according to the page on [Jack Kerouac](http://dbpedia.org/page/Jack_Kerouac), there are triples like

```
dbpedia:On_the_Road dbpedia-owl:author dbpedia:Jack_Kerouac
dbpedia:On_the_Road dbpprop:releaseDate "1957-09-05"^^xsd:date
```

Those might be useful starting points.

> I want to put a table into RDF/XML but I never did before.

You might find [Defining N-ary Relations on the Semantic Web](http://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/) useful.